# AWS API Gateway validator doesn't work for Custom Domain Name

Tags: aws-api-gateway

Having set up an API and a JSON validator model for the request body, it all works and tests correctly using the Default Endpoint.

When using a custom domain name, the validator seems to be bypassed, I'm missing a configuration step somewhere but can't see where.

Having searched around, I think I'm following all the correct steps. Has anyone else come across this problem?

I've tried

- up issuing the stage and re-depolying the API (and reconfigured the custom domain mapping to match)
- editing the model saving and then re-deploying the API
- I've used the Test function under the Resources / POST method where the model is configured (this has the expected result of only accepting validated bodies)
- I'm using Postman 'externally' using the default endpoint and this too has the desired result (only accepts valid body contents)
- I'm using Postman on the external custom domain name and the lambda function fires no matter what the body contents is, it's not being validated.